# How to reverse hash to string conversion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have simple hash and convert it to a string.

```
hash = {"description" => "test"}
=> {"description"=>"test"}

str = hash.to_s
=> "{\"description\"=>\"test\"}"
```

How can I convert this `str` to hash again ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need conversion from JSON to hash. (See [DOCS](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_json)). But, when you do `to_s` the output is not in pure JSON format. So, you may see I'm using `gsub` to replace `=>` with `:`

```
require 'json'

hash = {"description" => "test"}
=> {"description"=>"test"}

str = hash.to_s.gsub("=>", ":")
=> "{\"description\":\"test\"}"

JSON.parse(str)
=> {"description"=>"test"}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.

Comment: prefer `#to_json` to `#to_s.gsub` as the latter will be wrong in cases like `{ "description" => "some => text" }`

Comment: @rampion I'm doing it because OP has `to_s` in the question. Otherwise there is no meaning doing `JSON.parse(str.to_json)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` like that:

```rb
hash = {"description" => "test"}
=> {"description"=>"test"}

str = hash.to_s
=> "{\"description\"=>\"test\"}"

eval(str)
=> {"description"=>"test"}
```